# Filter multiple fields in only one JSONPath expression

Tags: java, jsonpath

Given the following input JSON:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": "some root string",
  "c":
  {
    "d": "some inner string"
  }
  "e": "ignored field"
}
```

Is it possible to obtain the following JSON using a JSONPath expression?

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": "some root string",
  "d": "some inner string"
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: JSON Path is a language for querying JSON data.  You're looking for data transformation.  You'll need a different tool.

Comment: Your comment makes sense but for example the following expression is valid in JSONPath: '$. ["a"," b"]', this way I can filter first level fields, what I am not achieving is filtering nested fields.

Comment: My point is that you're not going to be able to get the output JSON you show. You're only going to get a collection of values.  Some JSON Path implementations support dotted paths inside the selector, but that not typical.

Answer (score 2):

Below JsonPath should give you the expected output. However it depends on the type of Implementation.

```
$..['a','b','d']
```

JSONPath Evaluator : https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

**[Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)**

You need to set the option **Return null for missing leaf**

[image]

**[Stefan Goessner JsonPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)**

It returns all the values without having to select any options.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this has a problem that does not support duplicated inner fields, for example having a field called the same (eg. "id") inside distinct root fields (eg. "a" and "b"). This is a common case in the JSONs I need to process.

Comment: @JoaquínFernández if you could update the sample json and expected output based on your comments. I will be happy to play around.